# Counting sort review

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

I've just wrote a program in C# for counting sort.

- space complexity is O(N+K)
- time complexity is O(N+K)

I want reviews on my code and any better ways to implement this.

```
namespace SortingSelfCoded
{
    public static class CountingSorter
    {
        public static int[] CountingSort(int [] input)
        {
            // O(1)
           int max = input[0];

            // O(N)
            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            {
               if (input[i] > max)
                {
                    max = input[i];
                }
            }

            // Space complexity O(N+K)
            int[] counts = new int[max + 1];
            int[] output = new int[input.Length];


            // O(N)
            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            {
                counts[input[i]]++;
            }

            int j=0;
            // O(N+K)
            for (int i = 0; i < counts.Length; i++)
            {
                while (counts[i] > 0)
                {
                    output[j] = i;
                    j++;
                    counts[i]--;
                }
            }

            return output;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a practical use point of view:

1. I'd use `input.Max()` (LINQ) to obtain the maximum. Less code to write and does the same.
2. While it is ok to use single letter variables for loop counter `j` is not really a loop counter. It's the index of the current element so I would rename `j` into `currentIndex`.
3. Consider changing your last while loop into a for loop. This avoids mutating the state of the `count` array (saves you a read and write on every iteration):

   ```
   for (int k = 0; k < count[i]; k++)
   {
        output[currentIndex++] = i;
   }
   ```
4. Even on a 64 bit system the size of an array is limited to 2GB. So if your largest key is in the vicinity of `Int32.Max / 4` or larger then you will get an `OutOfMemoryException`. Depending what else you are doing in your program you will get it much earlier. If you are experimenting around with sorting algorithms then there are [some interesting approaches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_sorting#Algorithms_for_small_keys) reducing the key space.